# Need help implementing logic in an Android app with an Arduino website button.

Tags: android, logic, arduino

## Background story:

I have an [Arduino](http://arduino.cc) with a Wishield from [Async Labs](http://asynclabs.com/) wired up to a garage door opener. The Arduino throws up a website with a button. You push the button and the page refreshes with the new status of the button (on or off). The only problem is the pin (and by association the garage door remote) is set to on all the time. I made an Android app that gets the data from this web page and "pushes" the button from the app.

## Problem:

Everything in the Arduino and my Android app works fine, what I need is some kind of logic inside the app. I just can't get my head around how or where to implement the logic. I'd like to be able to push the button once and it open the door, open the circuit, and then close the circuit. Right now it works like this:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Door   |  Circuit
closed |  off    -- default: door closed circuit off
open   |  on     -- button pushed 1st time: door open circuit on
open   |  off    -- button pushed 2nd time: door open circuit off
closed |  on     -- button pushed 3rd time: door closed circuit on
closed |  off    -- button pushed 4th time: door closed circuit off
```

I think it should work like this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Door   |  Circuit
closed |  off    -- default: door closed circuit off
open   |  on     -- button pushed 1st time: door open circuit on
open   |  off    -- after a set time app automatically closes circuit
closed |  on     -- button pushed 2nd time: door closed circuit on
closed |  off    -- after a set time app automatically closes circuit
```

### Relevant code:

```
//Http Task
private class httpTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
HttpResponse responseGet = null;
HttpEntity resEntityGet = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        EditText01 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
        GetMethod test = new GetMethod();
        String returned;
        try {
            returned = test.getInternetData();

                if (pinCheck == 2){

                if(returned.toString().contains("\"Opener 2\">Door Closed")){  //"\"Opener 2\">Door Closed"
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Opening the door.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    findViewById(R.id.button1).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dooropen);                  
                }
                if(returned.toString().contains("\"Opener 2\">Door Open")){
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Closing the door.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    findViewById(R.id.button1).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.doorclosed);                    
                }
                } 

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(GarageDoorOpenerActivity.this);
        dialog.setMessage("Working");
        dialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
      try {
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(customURL[0] + URL + customURL[1] + pin);
    responseGet = client.execute(get);  
    resEntityGet = responseGet.getEntity();
  } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
    return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void params) {
        if(dialog.isShowing())
            dialog.dismiss();
    if (resEntityGet != null) {  
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Done. ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        resEntityGet = null;
    }
    }
}

public class GetMethod {
    public String getInternetData() throws Exception{
        BufferedReader in = null;
        String data = null;
        try{
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            URI url = new URI(customURL[0] + URL + customURL[1]); //customURL[0] + URL + customURL[1]
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
            request.setURI(url);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
            String l = "";
            String nl = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            while ((l = in.readLine()) !=null){
                sb.append(l + nl);              
            }
            in.close();
            data = sb.toString();
            return data;
        } finally{
            if (in !=null){
                try{
                    in.close();
                    return data;
                } catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

If anyone would like to make their own version of this I can post the full Android and Arduino code. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand of your description, you have everything in place, except a timed task to turn off the circuit after each button press.

Initiating a count-down timer on each button press, could work. 
See, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

Here is an example

```
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) { //30 seconds count-down

 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
     //no need to do anything here
 }

 public void onFinish() {
     turnOffCircuit(); 
 }
}.start();
```

Cool stuff with the Arduino. Actually bought my first Arduino kit yesterday :)

Comment: I love the Arduino. My first project landed on HackADay.com (search daft punk coffee table) if you need help... I'm not expert but I'm willing to try. Anyway... so when it was done I could just call the onButtonPressed(); function, right? It would "press" the button and close the circuit. But I'd have to have some kind of counter so that the image to my button doesn't show "closed" when it was just closing the circuit... or maybe I could just skip updating the photo the second time around. Thanks for this. I'll look into it more tonight.

Comment: It seems like it could work but I can't seem to implement it correctly. I had a counter setup and on the first run it changes a background image and does its thing. On the second run it did everything but update the image (because the image shows if the door is open or closed not the circuit state) The problem I'm running into is that the check for the second run is always true and so every 30 seconds it activates itself and the app hangs eventually and force closes.